# Run code after executing promise in Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, axios

I am trying to save to json the values returned from indeed api. I use indeed-scraper code from github https://github.com/rynobax/indeed-scraper

My code:

```
... required files ...

const parsedResults = []

indeed.query(queryOptions).then(response => {

    response.forEach((res,i) => {
        setTimeout(function(){

    let url = res.url
    let resultCount = 0

    console.log(`\n  Scraping of ${url} initiated...\n`)

    const getWebsiteContent = async (url) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(url)
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data)

        ...get scraped data...
        
        parsedResults.push(metadata)
        } catch (error) {
            exportResults(parsedResults)
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
    getWebsiteContent(url)
    
}
, i*3000);
    });
    });
const outputFile = 'data.json'
const fs = require('fs');
const exportResults = (parsedResults) => {
  fs.writeFile(outputFile, JSON.stringify(parsedResults, null, 4), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(`\n ${parsedResults.length} Results exported successfully to ${outputFile}\n`)
  })
}
```

parsedResults is not accessible in last portion of script, so to save as json file.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: To run code after a promise put that code inside its `.then()` method

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This is not working because I need for the async function getWebsiteContent() to finish executing

Comment: The indentation of your code is ... "interesting".